# Application crashing on getting updated information from database using timer and storing it on local data structures

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In our multi - user application we are continuously interacting with database. We have a common class through which we are sending POST queries to database and obtaining xml files in return. We are using delegates of NSXMLParser to parse the obtained file. The problem with us is we are facing many crashes in it generally when application is idle and changed data in database is being fetched in background through timer which is invoked after every few seconds. We have also dealt with error handling through try and catch but it proves to be of no use in this case and mostly application crashes with following error : 
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000020
Strange thing is that many times the fetching of updated data at background works very fine, same methods being successfully executed under similar conditions but suddenly it crashes on one of them. 
The codes we are using is as follows:

```
// we are using timer in this way:
chkOnlineUser=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15 target:mmObject selector:@selector(threadOnlineUser) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];


// this method being called in timer
-(void)threadOnlineUser{//HeartBeat in Thread
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(onlineUserRefresh) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

// this performs actual updation
-(void)onlineUserRefresh{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool =[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    @try{
        if(chkTimer==1){
            return;
        }
        chkTimer=1;

        if([allUserArray count]==0){
            [user parseXMLFileUser:@"all" andFlag:3];
            [allUserArray removeAllObjects];
            [allUserArray addObjectsFromArray:[user users]];
        }
        [objHeartBeat parseXMLFile:[loginID intValue] timeOut:10];
        NSMutableDictionary *tDictOL=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        tDictOL=[objHeartBeat onLineList];

        NSArray *tArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
        tArray=[[tDictOL objectForKey:@"onlineuser"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        [loginUserArray removeAllObjects];
        for(int l=0;l less than [tArray count] ;l++){
            int t;//=[[tArray objectAtIndex:l] intValue];
            if([[allUserArray valueForKey:@"Id"] containsObject:[tArray objectAtIndex:l]]){
                t = [[allUserArray valueForKey:@"Id"] indexOfObject:[tArray objectAtIndex:l]];
                [loginUserArray addObject:[allUserArray objectAtIndex:t]];
            }
        }
        [onlineTable reloadData];

        [logInUserPopUp removeAllItems];
        if([loginUserArray count]==1){
            [labelLoginUser setStringValue:@"Only you are online"];
            [logInUserPopUp setEnabled:YES];
        }else{
            [labelLoginUser setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %d users online",[loginUserArray count]]];
            [logInUserPopUp setEnabled:YES];
        }

        NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"menu"];
        NSMenuItem *itemOne = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
        [menu addItem:itemOne];
        for(int l=0;l less than [loginUserArray count];l++){
            NSString *tempStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[[loginUserArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"user_fname"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]],[[[loginUserArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"user_lname"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
            if(![tempStr isEqualToString:@""]){
                NSMenuItem *itemOne = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:tempStr action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
                [menu addItem:itemOne];
            }else if(l==0){
                NSMenuItem *itemOne = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:tempStr action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
                [menu addItem:itemOne];
            }
        }
        [logInUserPopUp setMenu:menu];

        if([lastUpdateTime isEqualToString:@""]){
        }else {
            [self fetchUpdatedInfo:lastUpdateTime];


            [self fetchUpdatedGroup:lastUpdateTime];// function same as fetchUpdatedInfo
            [avObject fetchUpdatedInfo:lastUpdateTime];// function same as fetchUpdatedInfo
            [esTVObject fetchUpdatedInfo:lastUpdateTime];// function same as fetchUpdatedInfo
        }

        lastUpdateTime=[[tDictOL objectForKey:@"lastServerTime"] copy];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        [queryByPost insertException:@"MainModule" inFun:@"onlineUserRefresh" excp:[e description] userId:[loginID intValue]];
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Error Panel", @"Main Module- onlineUserRefresh....%@", @"OK", nil, nil,e);
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"Internal Update Before Bye");
        chkTimer=0;
        NSLog(@"Internal Update Bye");// Some time application crashes after this log

        // Some time application crahses after "Internal Update Bye" log
    }
}

// The method which we are using to obtain updated data is of following form:
-(void)fetchUpdatedInfo:(NSString *)UpdTime{
    @try {
        if(initAfterLoginComplete==0){
            return;
        }

        [user parseXMLFileUser:UpdTime andFlag:[loginID intValue]];
        [tempUserUpdatedArray removeAllObjects];
        [tempUserUpdatedArray addObjectsFromArray:[user users]];
        if([tempUserUpdatedArray count]>0){
            if([contactsView isHidden]){
                [topContactImg setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"btn_contacts_off_red.png"]];
            }else {
                [topContactImg setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"btn_contacts_red.png"]];
            }
        }else {
            return;
        }
        int chkprof=0;
        for(int l=0;l less than [tempUserUpdatedArray count];l++){
            NSArray *tempArr1 = [allUserArray valueForKey:@"Id"];
            int s;
            if([[[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue]==profile_Id){
                chkprof=1;
            }
            if([tempArr1 containsObject:[[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"Id"]]){
                s = [tempArr1 indexOfObject:[[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"Id"]];
                [allUserArray replaceObjectAtIndex:s withObject:[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l]];
            }else {
                [allUserArray addObject:[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l]];
            }

            NSArray *tempArr2 = [tempUser valueForKey:@"Id"];
            if([tempArr2 containsObject:[[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"Id"]]){
                s = [tempArr2 indexOfObject:[[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"Id"]];
                [tempUser replaceObjectAtIndex:s withObject:[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l]];
            }else {
                [tempUser addObject:[tempUserUpdatedArray objectAtIndex:l]];
            }
        }

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"user_fname" ascending:YES];
        [tempUser sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
        [userListTableView reloadData];

        [groupsArray removeAllObjects];
        for(int z=0;z less than [tempGroups count];z++){
            NSMutableArray *tempMArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for(int l=0;l less than [allUserArray count];l++){
                if([[[allUserArray objectAtIndex:l] objectForKey:@"GroupId"] intValue]==[[[tempGroups objectAtIndex:z] objectForKey:@"group_id"] intValue]){
                    [tempMArr addObject:[allUserArray objectAtIndex:l]];
                }
            }
            [groupsArray insertObject:tempMArr atIndex:z];
            [tempMArr release];
            tempMArr= nil;
        }

        for(int n=0;n less than [tempGroups count];n++){
            [[groupsArray objectAtIndex:n] addObject:[tempGroups objectAtIndex:n]];
        }
        [groupsListOV reloadData];
        if(chkprof==1){
            [self profileShow:profile_Id];
        }else {
        }
        [self selectUserInTable:0];
    }@catch (NSException * e) {
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Error Panel", @"%@", @"OK", nil, nil,e);
    }
}

// The method which we are using to frame select query and parse obtained data is:
-(void)parseXMLForUser:(int)UId stringVar:(NSString*)stringVar{
    @try{

        if(queryByPost)
            [queryByPost release];

        queryByPost=[QueryByPost new];  // common class used to invoke method to send request via POST method

        //obtaining data for xml parsing
        NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from userinfo update_time >= '%@' AND NOT owner_id ='%d' ",stringVar,UId];

        NSData *obtainedData=[queryByPost executeQuery:query WithAction:@"query"];  // method invoked to perform post query

        if(obtainedData==nil){
            // data not obtained so return
            return;
        }

        // initializing dictionary to be obtained after parsing
        if(obtainedDictionary)
            [obtainedDictionary release];

        obtainedDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary new];

        // xml parsing
        if (updatedDataParser) // airportsListParser is an NSXMLParser instance variable 
            [updatedDataParser release]; 

        updatedDataParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:obtainedData];
        [updatedDataParser setDelegate:self]; 
        [updatedDataParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES]; 

        BOOL success = [updatedDataParser parse];  

    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"wtihin parseXMLForUser- parseXMLForUser:stringVar: - %@",[e description]);
    }

}
//The method which will attempt to interact 4 times with server if interaction with it is found to be unsuccessful , is of following form:
-(NSData*)executeQuery:(NSString*)query WithAction:(NSString*)doAction{
    NSLog(@"within ExecuteQuery:WithAction: Query is: %@ and Action is: %@",query,doAction);
    NSString *returnResult;
    @try {

        NSString *returnResult;
        NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest;
        NSError *error;
        NSData *searchData;
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
        postRequest=[self directMySQLQuery:query WithAction:doAction];  // this method sends actual POST request

        NSLog(@"after directMYSQL in QueryByPost- performQuery... ErrorLogMsg");
        searchData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        returnResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:searchData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSString *resultToBeCompared=[returnResult stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSLog(@"result obtained - %@/ resultToBeCompared - %@",returnResult,resultToBeCompared);


        if(![resultToBeCompared isEqualToString:@""]){
        }else {
            sleep(10);
            postRequest=[self directMySQLQuery:query WithAction:doAction];
            searchData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            if(![resultToBeCompared isEqualToString:@""]){
            }else {
                sleep(10);
                postRequest=[self directMySQLQuery:query WithAction:doAction];
                searchData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                if(![resultToBeCompared isEqualToString:@""]){
                }else {
                    sleep(10);
                    postRequest=[self directMySQLQuery:query WithAction:doAction];
                    searchData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                    if(![resultToBeCompared isEqualToString:@""]){
                    }else {
                        sleep(10);
                        postRequest=[self directMySQLQuery:query WithAction:doAction];
                        searchData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                        if(![resultToBeCompared isEqualToString:@""]){
                        }else {
                            return nil; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }




        returnResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:searchData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        return searchData;
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"within QueryByPost , execurteQuery:WithAction - %@",[e description]);
        return nil;     
    }
}

// The method which sends POST request to server , is of following form:
-(NSMutableURLRequest *)directMySQLQuery:(NSString*)query WithAction:(NSString*)doAction{   
    @try{
        NSLog(@"Query is: %@ and Action is: %@",query,doAction);

        // some pre initialization
        NSString *stringBoundary,*contentType;
        NSURL *cgiUrl ;
        NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest;
        NSMutableData *postBody;
        NSString *ans=@"434";

        cgiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://keysoftwareservices.com/API.php"];
        postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:cgiUrl];
        [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        stringBoundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0000ABCQueryxxxxxx"];
        contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", stringBoundary];
        [postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        //setting up the body:
        postBody = [NSMutableData data];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"code\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:ans] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:doAction] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"devmode\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"devmode"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"q\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:query] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postRequest setHTTPBody:postBody];

        NSLog(@"Direct My SQL ok");// Some time application crashes afte this log

        //Some time application crashes after "Direct My SQL ok" log
        return [postRequest mutableCopy];

    }@catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"NSException %@",e);
        NSRunAlertPanel(@"Error Panel", @"Within QueryByPost- directMySQLQuery...%@", @"OK", nil, nil,e);
        return nil;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I marked most of your question's body as code to try and make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a hard error.  It isn't an exception and you can't catch it.

It means your code has done something that tried to access memory that isn't valid.  Most likely, by trying to dereference a pointer that is trashed.   Over releases are a common way to achieve this kind of crash.

In this case, the cause of the crash is most likely because you are beating upon the user interface objects from a background thread.  Nothing is thread safe unless the documentation explicitly says it is thread safe and, even then, there may be limits as to what you can do from a thread.

Given the fatality of the lack of a proper threading model, I didn't look terribly closely at the rest of the code.  However, there were some obvious glaring problems with memory management; leaks and a likely over-release or two.

My recommendation would be to rewrite this code entirely.  Start by considering how to break up the problem along Model-View-Controller [MVC] lines.  Consider whether you can use the NSURL* and NSHTTP* classes to do the client/server communication -- if you can, they can be configured to do communications asynchronously.

As far as threading is concerned, you need to very carefully consider how to divide the problem up;  how to move the bits off of the main thread while not performing thread-unsafe actions upon the main thread.

Comment: Our application generally crashes after the last log of function without any wrong variable value. I am calling these functions in a timer (after every 25 secs).Crashing occurs spontaneously ie. it may crash after 1 hr or may crash after 15 min. If we use breakpoint to debug,application stops after every 25 secs :(
Reg:asynchronous communication, For this we have to use delegate method of NSURLConnection
but we need its output for next bit of code
as we need NSData as return from that function.. 

Is there any method by which we can execute next bit of code after the delegates call

Comment: Can't say this strongly enough: Stop trying to fix the symptoms and fix the problem.  This code, as written, is wrong;  dozens of bugs, but more importantly, the structure is flawed.  You need to take a step back and understand how to properly structure Cocoa applications before tackling this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try Matt Gallaghers inspirational uncaughtexceptionhandler. 
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html